# Android Webview (Phonegap): Disable Autocorrect, Autocapitalize and autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: android, webview, cordova

i have a problem with my loginpage which is loaded in a Webview on Android (Phonegap).
i used the attributes `autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off"` for my input fields and form tag but it doesn't work. the device shows simmilar words and the content goes up and down when i type a letter or number.

have anybody an idea how i can fix this problem?

cheers

Answer (score 10):

i have the same problem and after googling for hours , finally i got the solution

used the following attributes

autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"

I tested it on android 4.2 and its working

[Turn off predictive text for password field on websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298890/turn-off-predictive-text-for-password-field-on-websites)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these attributes apply to Android. They are iPhone specific. The autocorrect options are configured via the main Settings in Android.

Comment: Please follow @chandan's answer below. There seem to be options now in new versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a cordovasoftkeyboard plugin and show it on input text focus, hide it on blur. This avoid a lot of weird behaviors for me. However this will always show the basic soft keyboard (not the number soft, email soft etc...)

```
$(document).on({
        blur : function(){

            if(OS = "and")
                cordova.plugins.SoftKeyboard.hide();

        },
        focus : function(e){

            if(OS = "and"){
                e.preventDefault();
                cordova.plugins.SoftKeyboard.show();

                if(Windows.currentWindow == null){
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({//permet de scroller l'input en haut
                        scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top)-80//header
                    }, 800);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, ':input[type="text"],[type="number"],[type="email"]');
```

https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard

Answer (score -4):

I just discovered it!, you only have to add into your input this: `name="password"` and that solves it.

Comment: In most forms you need the name attribute for how its intended to be used.

Comment: Very creative solution indeed :)