# Turning off auto-complete for textarea and inputfields in Android Cordova-app

Tags: android, input, autocomplete, textarea, cordova

I'm working on an Android app (2.3.3) using Cordova (1.9.0), html5, javascript.

It's a language training tool so when users type their answers in textareas or inputfields, I don't want them to see suggestions.

I've tried autocomplete="off" in the textarea and input tag as well as in the form tag, but neither work. Does anyone know how to turn these suggestions off?

my test-html looks like this:

```html
<div><b>With form:</b>
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <p>Wie   <input size="5" value="b" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">  jij?</p>
        <textarea spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div><b>No form:</b>
    <p>Jan, ik   <input size="5" value="b" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">  Jan.</p>
    <textarea spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
</div>
```

Update:
I created a html-testpage and browsed there using an Android-phone, still experiencing the same autocompletion/suggestion-issue. So perhaps this is not a Cordova-app issue, but an Android browser issue? 
Take a look (on an Android phone) http://jsfiddle.net/f3AJq/

Comment: edited post and added some example code

Comment: How is the HTML linked with Android? Are you having troubles with the HTML input or with the Android EditText?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The Cordova-app shows a HTMLpage and if I enter text in the input/textarea, the androidkeyboard shows up with suggestions. I would like to know if I can switch the suggestions off in the HTML, the Android EditText or somewhere else.

Comment: @Kanarie: if you have a problem with the input and textarea then the main.xml is not relevant because you are not using that one?

Comment: @PoweRoy: Thanks, I think you're right. I created a html-page and when I browse there, there's the same problem.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it simply is not possible yet on Android?  That would be a real bummer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Webview (Phonegap): Disable Autocorrect, Autocapitalize and autocomplete doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849443/android-webview-phonegap-disable-autocorrect-autocapitalize-and-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up until at least Android 4.4 in cordova apps, the html5 attribute autocomplete="off" as described above does not have any effect. 
However on Android 6 the autocomplete="off" does work!

So it depends on the Android version, not the html.

(This is a cordova 5.1.1 android platform, in case anyone is wondering)

Comment: It does indeed work for most devices, but for **Samsung devices** it does **not** work as they use their own keyboard which doesn't respect html attributes for autocomplete. :'(

Answer (score 2):

try `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` in you EditText

Comment: this works only in native EditTexts, no html components loaded in a webview.

Comment: How to add this in index.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I Just discovered it!, it's so easy!, just put into the input: `name="password"`
Just it!

Comment: Instead of posting 2 exactly the same answers on different questions, please flag one of the questions as a duplicate if you think that both questions are essentially the same.

Comment: @BenClayton Try to add too autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"

Comment: Nothing else was working for me, but this one is! I use Cordova with Ionic v1.