# How to disable auto complete on a Samsung smartphone (Android) in a Cordova Project?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I can't figure out how to disable auto complete on an Android Samsung device in my Cordova project.
When a user tries to type in his email address, it changes completely what the user typed in. Even a dot is replaced by two dots, this is not acceptable for the user.

I already tried to add attributes into the html form, but this didn't work.

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

I also tried to override the webview in the android project (Java code), but this didn't work either.

```
webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
WebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
WebView.clearFormData();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this: 
`<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />`

(credits : https://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect )

Comment: This works on all other Android devices, but not on the Samsung devices. It seems like Samsung overrides the html attributes in a Cordova app.

Comment: try here, then :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968624/prevent-samsung-predictive-text-in-html-form

Comment: It's not a browser issue as it works on other non-Samsung phones with the same Android version. Samsung made his own autocomplete feature that overrides the default one in Android. It also doesn't look to the HTML attributes.

Comment: autocomplete does work fine for me on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2016 (Android 7.0)