# Samsung mobile keyboard duplicates letters with onkeyup listener

Tags: javascript, react-native, samsung-mobile, keyup

I'm writing a simple code that converts typed letters to uppercase and then refill this uppercased letters to an input element on keyup() event.

But I'm getting a confusing issue: when typing letters on my Samsung mobile (Galaxy Note 5), I get duplicated letters like the below image:

[image: ss]

The above, I use the default Samsung keyboard with Vietnamese language and Google chrome browser. But when I try to switch the language to English, I don't see the issue.

I have some tests and here are the results:
Test 1:
Samsung keyboard + Vietnamese language
Chrome / or Samsung browser
-> the issue happens

Test 2:
Samsung keyboard + English language
Chrome / or Samsung browser
-> the issue does not happen

Test 3:
Samsung keyboard + Vietnamese language
Firefox browser
-> the issue does not happen

Test 4:
Google keyboard + Vietnamese language
Chrome / or Samsung browser
-> the issue does not happen

Here is the code:

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText">

<script>
  document.getElementById('inputText').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var typedLetters = this.value;
    var upperCasedLetters = typedLetters.toUpperCase();
    this.value = upperCasedLetters;
  });
</script>
```

I have read a similar issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068, but I do not find yet a clear solution until now.

Can someone tell me what's going on? and How to solve this issue programmatically?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found out how to deal with this problem by applying "password field" trick as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111105/4006731.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `text-transform: uppercase;` ?? Pure CSS solution.

```css
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText">
```

Comment: because it simply does not fit my requirement, the above is just a piece of my code, there are other things that need to be processed after that

Comment: if so, you need to have more details in your post. The post seem to be saying you have an issue getting characters from lower to uppercase. This is a typical [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: adding to this, no matter what the logic is, uppercasing is a UI representation, which you can achieve through CSS. It's best recommended not to overcomplicate your code. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: CSS solution does not keep transform (uppercase) when submitted in the form as one of my requirements

Comment: because this issue is hard to recreate, the alternate solution is to convert the value before submit to uppercase.

Comment: thanks, but that solution is not what i am looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198758/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-kaid).

Answer (score 0):

I found that autocapitalize solved the problem for me:

```
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="characters" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter Text"/>
```

This essentially turned on the caps lock of the keyboard. Placeholder text remained as written (caps and lower), the caps weren't a "trick of the eye" like the CSS text-transform approach, and is MUCH simpler than the password field hack.