# cordova android: remove suggestions

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, keycode

I have a cordova app (with ionic2). I'd like to remove the autocomplete/suggestion/autocorrect/... bar on soft keyboard for specific input.

Is it possible ?

I already try with attributes like `spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"` but it change nothing.

Also after multiple lectures, my problem look comming from the event keycode 229.
But I found nothing to manage the inserted input correctly.
So the idea was to remove this autocomplete bar to avoid these keycode.

When I use a password input type it's working properly. Of course, I saw disc in places of characters. And I need to see characters. For these purpose I tried to remove them with css text-security but of course, it's not working for input type password...

An other solution could probably be accessing the native keyboard or the native input with custom cordova plugin. But I don't know how to access to linked EditText with Cordova.

Any ideas ?

Regards

Comment: Looks like this is only partially possible -- Android > 4.4 and NOT a Samsung: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327968/turning-off-auto-complete-for-textarea-and-inputfields-in-android-cordova-app