# How to Disable the word suggestion strip in keyboard in ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, passwords

I want to disable the word suggestion (the line above the keyboard with thus this thos thi thik tha) in my ionic app [image: keyboard with word suggestion strip]
I have tried autocomplete="off",autocaptiliaze ="off" and all those properties but they are not working

[image: Keyboard without word suggestion strip when it is of type keyboard]

i want a keyboard without word suggestion strip .. the one like when it comes for password type...can anyone suggest anything that helps... and i want the solution for ionic cordova apps not the native android or ios

Comment: Auto-complete is user config on the keyboard, AFAIK you can't disable it

Comment: @Zoe yeah... but I need a way around.. the word suggestion strip doesn't come in type password.... is there any option for removing the asterisks from input type password

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" is the flag for android  . In ionic i don't know if its available or not. But there must be an alternative.

Comment: i cant seem to find the alternative for that @ADM

Comment: Well, Keep searching . i don't know anything about ionic right now.

Comment: @LuckyStarr what benefit will I get by editing the manifest.xml? sorry but i dont understand what you trying to say

Answer (score -1):

You can disable suggestions on the Soft Keyboard by adding the following line in the xml **Edittext**.

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: this is for native android. I need the solution for hybrid apps..... ionic/cordova @hemant-parmar

Comment: ok , have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327968/turning-off-auto-complete-for-textarea-and-inputfields-in-android-cordova-app

Comment: i am using android version 7 on nexus 6 but it is still not working