# Ionic - How to disable keyboard suggestions on Android keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework

1. I've tried all ion-textarea possibilities such as type="email" and so on, I can't make it work on all Android versions.
2. I've installed cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard, which shows the keyboard without suggestions (Image A). But when I tap the ion-textarea, the native keyboard shows instead (Image B).

How can I solve this, either disabling suggestions on the native keyboard or having the Cordova plugin replace the native keyboard for my ion-textarea, or maybe something else? Thanks!

Image A

[image]

Image B

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, on my Pixel with Android 9 `<ion-textarea inputmode="email"></ion-textarea>` worked :).

Comment: While this disables the traditional suggestions, the currently typed word will still appear right above the keyboard in a similar fashion. So if anyone wonders: this will not get rid of the bar that appears above the keyboard, unlike for example this does in flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61537289/20009330

Answer (score 0):

Try `autocomplete="off"` tag

Up until at least Android 4.4 in cordova apps, the html5 attribute `autocomplete="off"` not have any effect. However on Android 6 the `autocomplete="off"` does work! So it depends on the Android version.

It does indeed work for most devices, but for Samsung devices it does not work as they use their own keyboard which doesn't respect html attributes for autocomplete.

source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327968/turning-off-auto-complete-for-textarea-and-inputfields-in-android-cordova-app)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've made a blank project and add this single line in ion-content: <ion-input autocomplete="off"></ion-input>. The suggestions shows on my Pixel, Android version 9. What do I do wrong?

Comment: autocomplete="off" works with normal inputs <input autocomplete="off"> not ionic inputs

Comment: Finally, on my Pixel with Android 9 only <input type="email"> worked! Thanks for telling me to use input instead of ion-input. But nothing works with textarea so far :(.