# How to disable predictive text in TextField of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, autocorrect

I want to disable predictive text which comes in the keyboard of a textfield. It is not so difficult in native android and IOS but I have not found a solution in a Flutter.

[image]

I have tried using autocorrect: false and changing keyboardtypes but it is not working.

```
TextField(
          autocorrect: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter text"),
          autofocus: true,
        ),
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If neither `enableSuggestions` nor `autocorrect` can solve the problem, try setting `keyboardType` to **TextInputType.visiblePassword**.

Comment: TextInputType.visiblePassword works but I need multiline button in keyboard

Comment: enableSuggestions: false worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can try to add `enableSuggestions = false` to your textfield widget. This should disable the predictive text from your keyboard as supposed to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42550.

```
TextField(
      autocorrect: false,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter text"),
      autofocus: true,
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing this answer, this is not yet available in Android. But using autocorrect: false on iOS should work fine.

Check: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22828

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on both iOS and android

```
                    TextField(
                        autocorrect: false,
                        obscureText: true,
                        controller: answerText,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        autofocus: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            result = value;
                          });
                        },),
```

The only downside is that it obscure from the screen what is written. A workaround is to add somewhere in the screen `Text(result)`