# Ionic Capacitor (Angular): How to disable keyboard bar (predictive text, mic-toggle, etc.) on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Note this is not a duplicate since this question:

[Ionic - How to disable keyboard suggestions on Android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093730/ionic-how-to-disable-keyboard-suggestions-on-android-keyboard)

was asked in Januray 2019, thus for Ionic Cordova (Ionic Capacitor was not a thing back then yet).

For my inputs keyboard, predictive text is enabled by default somehow, but only for Android, not on IOS. However predictive (& all the other tools in that toolbar) make absolutely no sense for my app, since my app uses its own predictive text.

I tried setting various things like:

autocomplete=“off”

autocorrect=“off”

spellcheck=“false”

inputmode="email" (source: [Ionic - How to disable keyboard suggestions on Android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093730/ionic-how-to-disable-keyboard-suggestions-on-android-keyboard))

onto the `<ion-input>`

but they all did not solve the problem.

Those are two pictures, first when not having entered, second after entering something:

[image: this toolbar should go away in general]

[image: with inputmode="email" this displays instea]

The second image shows that the solution from 2019 doesnt work anymore, as now no predictive text gets displayed but still 'something' gets displayed.

I do not want that bar to be displayed at all, since My app needs as much vertical space as possible.

Maybe there exists a workaround e.g. like this one in Flutter:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61537289/20009330