# Disable mobile keyboard cache on cordova, ionic & angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing app that is for both Android and Ios. I have need to disable keyboard cache and have only found native solution that are not useful in this case. So the question is that is there any way to achieve this for both operatingsystems using cordova or ionic?

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.6
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.19
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.19
@angular/cli                  : 8.3.19
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v14.0.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.14.4
OS     : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "disabling keyboard cache" exactly? Your app cannot and **must not** mess with the user's keyboard settings or storage.

Maybe you are looking for a way to [disable suggested words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093730/ionic-how-to-disable-keyboard-suggestions-on-android-keyboard).

Comment: Hi, goal is to prevent phone from storing words typed in the app.